# How to insert a script into Dojo html file?

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I have HTML dojo file and I want to add a div tag which has a script tag inside it. I am new to DOjo and I am not sure how I can add script in dojo's html.
I want to add somehting like below in my html:

```html
<div name="abc">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://something/somehitng">
  </script>
  <script type="xxx" key1=value1 key2=value2>
  </script>
  <button id="b1" onclick="onButtonClick()">
      click
     </button>
</div>
<script>
  function onButtonClick() {
    do something;
  }
</script>
```

but dojo is not executing a script. Request your help in understanding this.

Comment: `do something;` is very invalid JavaScript.

Comment: Could you please explain the reason why do you want to do this? Maybe there is another option.  
Reason why this doesn't work may be following: if you add script in a template file of some dojo widget, this template is added to the DOM after the window is fully loaded. I'm not 100% sure, but this may be the case. So you can add these scripts into you index.html if it's possible.